# Побайтовое вычитание с нижней границей

Tags: c++, c

Это вопрос из моей постоянной рубрики. Нужно вычесть 2 `uint32_t` так, чтобы байты вычитались отдельно, и при этом `a - b = 0` если `a < b` . Например `0x02.00.00 - 0x01.00.10 = 0x01.00.00`

> Как всегда без if-ов(тернарных операторов), simd инструкций и прочих благ цивилизации.

Comment: Вас в прошлый раз почему то устроил ответ с использованием `-(res <= x)`, а с точки зрения ассемблера оператор `<=` - это 100% IF. А такими скрытыми if можете спокойно побайтно проверить и вычесть когда надо

Comment: Про `<=` для ассемблера не знал. Выбрал самый лаконичный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t bytes_dozu32(uint32_t x,uint32_t y) {
 uint32_t xr=x ^ y;
 uint32_t su=(x | 0x80808080)-(y & 0x7F7F7F7F);// Безопасно вычитаем младшие 7 бит байтов
 return ~( (xr | 0x7F7F7F7F) ^ su) & (((       // Объединяем разность 8х бит и младшие
           (~xr & su) |   // 8е биты x/y равны - 8е биты su говорят, что не было переноса
           (xr & x))  &   // 8e биты x/y НЕ равны - x > y если 8й бит x=1
            0x80808080)>>7)*255; // Оставляем только 8е биты и распространяем их на весь байт
}
int main(void)
{
 uint32_t x=0x027FED01;
 uint32_t y=0x01857E10;
 printf("%08x -\n%08x =\n",x,y);
 printf("%08x\n",bytes_dozu32(x,y));
}
```

Результат:

```
027fed01 -
01857e10 =
01006f00
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде ответ уже есть в вопросе. Байты отдельно? - значит разложить uint32 на 4 байта. вычесть байты 2х чисел попарно (если первое больше второго, или 0). Потом эти побайтные разницы с учетом весов поскладывать в одно 32 битное число

Если нужны детали, разложить - это побитовое & с соотв. маской (0xff , 0xff00, 0xff0000 и 0xff000000) и сдвиг вправо на 0, 8, 16 или 24 бита соответственно.
собрать в кучку - это соответственно умножение частичных сумм на 1, 0x100, 0x10000 и 0x1000000 соответственно, и сложить эти 4 произведения